# Mysql Not Accepting Connections

Tags: mysql, solaris

Today Mysql Innodb Data files maxed out.  I was attempted to clear out files in order to reduce the size.  This my be completely unrelated to the issue, but I thought it would be worth mentioning.

I restarted the computer and now Mysql is refusing all outside connections.  Their are no errors in the error log.  However, if I disable Innodb it works, but the Innodb is disabled.  I need the Innodb working, and the server accepting connections.

"Can't connect to MySQL server on '' (111) [2003]"  111 meaning that its refusing the connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have this issue leave it alone and give it time.  It takes quite a while for it to load the database and you will be able to use something to remove some of the database information in order to return it to a working status.

You may also be able to dump the database and work on it that way.

Answer (score 0):

If it's refusing the connections, then (short of firewall shenanigans not in evidence) then MySQL isn't running.  More specifically, given the whole InnoDB/non-InnoDB startup difference, trying to use InnoDB is causing a failure to start.  Your MySQL logs will tell you exactly why, but if you've been fiddling with InnoDB data files, I'd say there's a chance you might be restoring from backups in the near future.

Comment: There are no errors in the log though.  When I change it and break it there are, but when I start it up normally there is no error.   I actually need help, please do not down vote it.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but playing with your innodb file manually is causing MySQL to fail to startup (which is why it does when you disable innodb in the config).

My MySQL skills are not great, but my guess is you've hosed your database, and are going to need to restore from a backup. You might be able to force an innodb recovery ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html )

In the future I'd read the docs before you touch anything with MySQL, especially it's data files, manually. Here's a nice little section that will be helpful in the future  [Adding, Removing, or Resizing InnoDB Data and Log Files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-data-log-reconfiguration.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

1. Check the file system messages by running "dmesg | tail" , checking for a corrupted file system journal.
2. If journal is bad, run the command "tune2fs -j [device name]"

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem happen, your database server is going to do it's best to get things back up and running.  Make sure to disable any other servers attempting to make contact with it and give it 6-12 hours.  It will get back up and running and allow you to clear out an old data and it will restore functionality.